# nhibernate component mapping by code reuse with different columns

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I would like to reuse a Period Class on several Entities. It is based an a legacy schema where column names are not consistent.
Since I would like to reuse this one period class in several occasions, I thought I provide multiple mappings with their correspondent column names. But my plan did not work because nhibernate seems to work only with one mapping per entity even if it's a component.

Is there any other way to reuse this Component with different underlying column names?

```
public class Period
{
    public virtual DateTime From {get;set;}
    public virtual DateTime To {get;set;}
}


public class PeriodMapping
{
    public static Action<IComponentMapper<Period>> ForPolicy()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Property(p => p.From, map => map.Column("CommencementDate"));
            c.Property(p => p.To, map => map.Column("ReasonForEnding"));
        };
    }

    public static Action<IComponentMapper<Period>> ForPasswordOfUser()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Property(p => p.From, map => map.Column("PasswordValidFrom"));
            c.Property(p => p.To, map => map.Column("PasswordValidUntil"));
        };
    }

    // several other mappings
}

public class PolicyMapping : ClassMapping<Policy>
{
    public VertragMapping()
    {
        Component(a => a.Period, PeriodMapping.ForPolicy());
    }
}

public class UserMapping : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public VertragMapping()
    {
        Component(a => a.Period, PeriodMapping.ForPasswordOfUser());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it like this.

```
public class PeriodMapping
{
    public static Action<ComponentPart<Period>> ForPolicy()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Map(p => p.From, "CommencementDate");
            c.Map(p => p.To, "ReasonForEnding");
        };
    }

    public static Action<ComponentPart<Period>> ForPasswordOfUser()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Map(p => p.From, "PasswordValidFrom");
            c.Map(p => p.To, "PasswordValidUntil");
        };
    }

    // several other mappings
}
```